# Can I still get escort quests in the early dungeons after I reach level 9?

Tags: tales-of-maj-eyal

I've noticed that while leveling up in the starter dungeons, I often run into fairly easy escort quests which can give me skill or stat gains. However, once I hit level 9 and enter these dungeons, it tells me the dungeon is too easy for me automatically takes me to the last level of the dungeon. I can backtrack up the stairs, and have a few times, but have never run into escort quests when going this direction.

Is it possible to get more escort quests when going from the bottom up after I hit level 9, or am I just wasting my time?

Answer (score 2):

The dungeon levels for escort quests (9 of them) are chosen during character generation (function onBirth in Player.lua). The quest should trigger the first time you enter each level on this list, unless it is so crowded that the game can't find a location for the escortee (in which case it may happen when you re-enter the level). I have had this happen when coming up the stairs.

Note that the list can also contain levels in non-starter dungeons, namely Daikara, Old Forest, Dreadfell, and Reknor.

Comment: So it sounds like, yes, I should walk backwards from the bottom level to see if I can trigger an escort quest (assuming I want to get all the escort quest rewards).

In other news, I was just reading that the 1.3 patch should make it optional whether you are taken to the bottom level automatically or not.

Comment: I've probably done this about 15-20 times now and have *never* had it trigger yet when working my way upward through a dungeon. Perhaps random is just random, but I'm curious if anyone else has ever had it work when working upward.

Comment: The one time I remember clearly was not of the "you go straight to the bottom variety", so that may make a difference - it was in Dreadfell, and the entry room had been full of undead when I first entered. I went further down, then got the quest on the way up.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I guess it ends up being irrelevant anyway since I still end up doing those levels for a little extra loot and xp.